# Property of Compact sets

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that the union of compact sets is compact.

Let $X,Y$ be compact sets and let $x_n\in\ X\cup Y$. Then, we have that there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ in $X$ or $Y$. Also, since $X$ and $Y$ are compact, it follows that the subsequence converges to some point in $X$ or $Y$.

Here is where I am not sure how to continue. Is this right so far?

Comment: You are working with sequential compactness, and of course in this case you are done, since  you have shown that any sequence in the union has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: The proof is fine.

Comment: The words "it follows that the subsequence converges to some point" should be replaced by "it follows that the subsequence has a further subsequence which converges to some point". Then you will be done by noting that a subsequence of a subsequence is a subsequence of the original sequence.

Comment: @Pam_22R: It depends on how pedantic you wan to be. I would simplify my life and just assume without loss of generality that there is an infinite subsequence in, say, $X$ and then you are finished since $X \subset X \cup Y$.

Comment: @Pam_22R: Well, yes & no. You could just simplify things by saying that at least one of $X,Y$ contain an infinite number of members of the sequence, WLOG you can assume they are in $X$. This is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

See, the definition is very simple : given a sequence in the set, there exists a convergent subsequence, which converges in the set itself. Then, the set is compact.

Now, what you have to start with is a sequence $x_n \in X \cup Y$. There is nothing to assume about the nature of this sequence at all. It is therefore not assumed convergent, as you have asked in the comments.

Now, as you have said, this sequence $x_{n}$ will have a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ contained entirely either in $X$ or $Y$, because the sequence is infinite, so if you split it in two parts depending upon whether that term is in $X$ or in $Y$, on of the parts will be infinite .Suppose it is contained in $X$ (i.e. there are infinitely many terms of $x_n$ which are contained in $X$, and these we call as $x_{n_k}$).

Now, $x_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$, but it is contained in $X$. Since $X$ is compact, and $x_{n_k}$ is a sequence in $X$, there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_{k_l}}$ of $x_{n_k}$, which converges in $X$ (to some point $x \in X$, if you like). Now, $x_{n_{k_l}}$ is a subsequence of $x_{n_k}$, which is a subsequence of $x_n$. So, $x_{n_{k_l}}$ is a convergent subsequence of $x_n$ (*and not $x_{n_k}$, as written in your answer*), which converges to a point $x \in X$, and therefore $x \in X \cup Y$.

Now, do the same thing as above, but instead assume that the subsequence $x_{n_k}$ is in $Y$ rather than in $X$. The argument is exactly the same, and you could write it out for practice if you like.

Therefore, $X \cup Y$ is compact.

Comment: Because $x$ is the limit of $x_{n_{k_l}}$, which is contained entirely in $X$. Therefore, $x \in X$ is  true, and since $X \subset X \cup Y$, clearly $x \in X \cup Y$. Then, you can prove the other case.

Comment: Oh right since $X$ is a subset then is it follows that $x\in\ X\cup Y$

Comment: Exactly! Now, you have to repeat the same thing for $Y$. If you are writing this in an exam, you can always say : do the same thing above for $Y$, and you should get full credit, because otherwise it's just rewriting the logic all over again.

Comment: I just forgot to ask one question, since $x_n$ is the sequence and $x_{n_k}$ is the subsequence, we have that any subsequence of $x_{n_k}$ is also a subsequnce of $X_n$, but why is this so? Is this because we are working with the same terms of the sequence?

Comment: Yes, this is because we are working with the terms of the same sequence. For example, the even numbers are a subsequence of the natural numbers, and the multiples of four are a subset of the even numbers, and therefore of  the natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine with the slight modification I noted in the comments.

You need to show that $X\cup Y$ is compact. This means that you need to show that every sequence in $X\cup Y$ has a convergent subsequence, so you fix $(x_n)$ in $X\cup Y$. The goal is to now find a subsequence of $(x_n)$ which converges.
As you noted, there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ which lies entirely in one of the two spaces. Let's assume without loss of generality that $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ in $X$. Then, by the compactness of $X$, the sequence $(x_{n_k})$ has a convergent subsequence in $X$. Hence there is a subsequence $(x_{n_{k_j}})$ of $(x_{n_k})$ such that $(x_{n_{k_j}})$ converges to an element in $X$. Since $(x_{n_{k_j}})$ is a subsequence of our original sequence $(x_n)$ which converges to a point in $X\subseteq X\cup Y$, then we are done. Therefore $X\cup Y$ is compact.

---

It was important to add this second subsequence because it isn't true that $(x_{n_k})$ will necessarily converge to something. Compactness only tells us that a subsequence will converge.

Also, in regards to your question about beginning with $x_n\to x$, the answer is no. The definition of compactness says that every sequence has a convergent subsequence. We can't assume our sequence already converges.

Comment: Yes, I now understand what you meant by your comment and I see now that we do not need to initially state the sequence converges because we just know that the subsequence converges to some point in the set.

Comment: @Pam_22R I'm glad I could help. Just to be super clear, it's not because we know (well, are able to show) that some subsequence converges. We have to assume what is required in the definition of compactness, which is an arbitrary sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{n: x_n\in X\}$ and $B=\{n: x_n\in Y\}.$ At least one of $A,B$ is an infinite set.

If $A$ is infinite let $A=\{f(n):N\in\Bbb N\}$ where $f(n)<f(n+1).$  The sequence $\sigma=(x_{f(n)})_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a sub-sequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}.$

All of the entries of $\sigma$ belong to $X$ so $\sigma$ has a sub-sequence $\tau$ converging to some $x\in X.$ Now $\tau$ is also a sub-sequence of $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ and of course $x\in X\cup Y.$

Similarly if $B$ is infinite.